# How can a jdbcTemplate execute an update statement and return variable

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am newbie to work on spring, and now I got a query but not sure how to use jdbcTemplate to work on it, the query is as follow:

UPDATE table set Seq = @seq := Seq + 1 WHERE id= ?; SELECT @seq as total;

I try to use jdbcTemplate.executeQuery but it will shows up error:
Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

I try to use jdbcTemplate.executeUpdate, but seems it only return affected row

Is there anyone know how I can achieve this query and return the updated value?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to execute the `UPDATE` statement first using [update](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-) and then execute the `SELECT` statement using [queryForObject](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-). The variable is persisted across the session bound to the same connection.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE table set Seq = @seq := Seq + 1 WHERE id= ?", yourId);
int total = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT @seq as total", Integer.class);
```

Comment: I have tried your code and the result for the total is null value. the goal of this query would like to increase a counter and return new counter value back to the program within the same query. and wish that if multiple connection is made at the same time, the query can return a right counter